# How to set a filename for "Content-Disposition: inline;" file on android device?

Tags: php, android, download, http-headers, content-disposition

Greeting.

There's a following set of header I use to process file being opened inline in browser window(usually it is PDF):

```
header("Content-Type: " . $mime[$ext]);
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" . $path_parts["basename"]);
header("Content-length: $fsize");
header("Cache-control: private");
```

This code is placed in **download.php** file to achieve extra steps being done before file is actually thrown to client. Where uri to file is set as get variable like this:

```
http://sitedotcom/download.php?=file=path-to-file.pdf
```

And the problem is the following. Desktop opens file inline in browser window, but android device downloads it and set filename to download.php instead of path-to-file.pdf. This causes misunderstanding and am looking for help.

Is there a way to setup header somehow so that file gets a correct name?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the apache module rewrite like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pdf/([^/\.]+)$ download.php?file=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The user will ask for:

```
http://sitedotcom/pdf/path-to-file.pdf
```

and the PHP will handle the URL

```
http://sitedotcom/download.php?file=path-to-file.pdf
```

So when the file will be saved it will be under "path-to-file.pdf"